# jquery image swap - for galleriffic

Tags: jquery, galleriffic

I have bit of a fiddly one here but I am basically attempting to put an image swap function into Galleriffic. I have been adapting the jquery Galleriffic image gallery to fit a client's needs and all is going well apart from this one function that I need to add.

http://www.susanyounganimation.com/test/drawings/carnival.html

Beneath the large image on the left is the text 'negative/positive'. The client wants the user to have the option to see a negative i.e. inverted version of the image when one clicks on 'negative' and then the image to revert back to the original when they click positive'. I have every image in the gallery as a negative version (exactly the same dimensions etc) so what I need to do is simply replace the current image with another when one clicks on the negative or positive text beneath.

Hope this all makes sense. Can anyone help me with some script that will enable this? Any comments welcome as I am at my wits end with this one!

All the best

S

Comment: is this the type of thing you're looking for http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-4.html

Comment: why don't you just view source?

Comment: @RachelGallen that is not what she's asking.  She's wanting to swap the main image with another one.

Comment: Thank you RuralJuror, you are right. I want the option of swapping the main image with another (of exactly the same dimensions) when one clicks the 'negative' button under the main image. I then want to return back to the original image when one clicks 'positive'.

Comment: see http://code.google.com/p/galleriffic/source/browse/trunk/example/js/jquery.galleriffic.js?r=8

Comment: why din't you just use the jquery swapimage function see examples on this page view-source:http://labs.xddnet.com/jquery-swapimage/example/example.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on that gallery, but here's how I would tackle the problem.  I would create the negative images and store them in the same folder as the main images, with a neg- added to the end of the file such as:

Painting-001.jpg

Painting-001-neg.jpg

Then add a click event handler for the the negative and positive link that would replace the current large image src with the same image, prepended with "neg-".

```
$("img#ID_OF_MAIN_IMAGE").src($(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg','-neg.jpg'));
```

And to restore it:

```
$("img#ID_OF_MAIN_IMAGE").src($(this).attr('src').replace('-neg.jpg','.jpg'));
```

You only need one instance of the positive/negative link, not one for each photo.

Let me know if this isn't clear

Comment: Thank you Rural, but still having problems. I have done as instructed but still don't know what to wrap the links in (excuse my ignorance). How do I activate (in html) the 'negative' and 'positive' text on the page so it will trigger the jquery?

Comment: @user2076700 Give each link a class, such as .link_negative and .link_positive.  Then trigger it like so:

$('.link_negative').click(function() {
  $("img#ID_OF_MAIN_IMAGE").src($(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg','-neg.jpg'));

});

Comment: Like this?
<span class="link_negative">negative</span>/<span class="link_positive">positive</span>